# Streaming MKV over RTP/RTSP (with trickplay)

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, vlc, rtsp, mkv

I really need some i help.

I have to stream .mkv files over rtp/rtsp. The streamed file could be under writing. For some addition, it have to use the "trickplay" functionality.(fast forward, rewind etc.)

I can use VLC as a client.

Could you mention some solution, or stackoverflow topic for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please note that asking for off-site resources and software recommendations are off topic here. See the [help] for more.

Comment: Corrected the recommendations, thank you!